# Unity GUI: inventory display off by one slot vertically

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem in my game. I'm creating a dynamic inventory display, and it looks the way I want it to save for one thing: the top row of slots is higher than the boundaries of the inventory by one row:

[image]

This is my method that does the work:

```
private void CreateLayout()
{
    slotsList = new List<GameObject>();
    numEmptySlots = numSlots;

    // Set inventory spacing.
    inventoryWidth = (numSlots/numRows) * (slotSize + slotPaddingLeft) + slotPaddingLeft;
    inventoryHeight = numRows * (slotSize + slotPaddingTop) + slotPaddingTop;
    inventoryRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    inventoryRect.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, inventoryWidth);
    inventoryRect.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, inventoryHeight);

    // Set dynamic row and column spacing.
    int numCols = numSlots/numRows;
    for (int y = 0; y < numRows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numCols; x++)
        {
            GameObject NewSlot = (GameObject) Instantiate(SlotPrefab);
            RectTransform newSlotRect = NewSlot.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            newSlotRect.localPosition = inventoryRect.localPosition + new Vector3((slotPaddingLeft * x) + slotPaddingLeft + (slotSize * x),
                                                                                -(slotPaddingTop * y) - slotPaddingTop - (slotSize * y));
            newSlotRect.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, slotSize);
            newSlotRect.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, slotSize);
            slotsList.Add(NewSlot);
        }
    }
}
```

Are my signs perhaps wrong somewhere, or maybe my origin? If I change the negative sign to positive in the -(slotSize * y) part, the slots flip completely to the top side fine, but if I keep the negative, they start one slot's height higher than they should like shown, flipping over seemingly the wrong pivot point.

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: Did you try making it positive?  -(slotPaddingTop * y)

Comment: I haven't looked that deeply at your code, but have you tried doing something like starting `x` and `y` at `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Neither of them ended up working, but what did is when I made "-(slotPaddingTop * y) - slotPaddingTop - (slotSize * y));" into "-(slotPaddingTop * y) - slotPaddingTop - (slotSize * y) - slotSize);"! :)